# How to use parameters in sql queries (sp_executesql not working as per requirement)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used temporary tables plus temporary variables..
Now when my sql queries are having both temporary variables and table, i got to know sp_executesql not working because we can't use temporary tables in it
and standard execution won't take the variable parameters.
So it will be very helpfull if anyone can help me out with some other solution for it?

This is a sample code :

```
create procedure tryit
as begin
declare @temp as Table_Type;

declare @ghdhj as nvarchar(50)
set @ghdhj='TBVHTempSelectionTable';

declare @sqlstatement nvarchar(max);
set @sqlstatement=N'insert into @temp select * from '+@ghdhj+';';
exec sp_executesql @sqlstatement;
--,@temp='finalResultTable',@ghdhj='TBVHTempSelectionTable'

select * from @temp;
end
go

exec tryit
```

Comment: I have attached a sample code.

Comment: You could separate the procedure in two parts - you can easily pass a read-only table variable to both `sp_executesql` and any stored procedure. So if you declare the table variable inside of the `sp_executesql`, you can easily call any stored procedure on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create temporary table and then execute `sp_executesql`

Comment: Consider explaining this answer more, and perhaps adding sample code to make it very clear.

Comment: i have already tried that, that's why am asking this question. you can see the sample code. which is not working.

Comment: @Sarthak That's not a temporary table, that's a table variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the temporary table first you should be able to access it in sp_executesql if you specify it explicitly

```
select *
into #peter
from (values (10), (10)) p(a);

exec sp_executesql N'insert into tempdb..#peter values (20), (20)';

select * from #peter;
-- Result
A
10
10
20
20
```

Answer (score 1):

sp_executesql can accept table valued parameters, so you can pass a table variable to sp_executesql.

First, you need a table type defined on your database. You create table types using CREATE TYPE statement. For example:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE 
( 
    CategoryID int, 
    CategoryName nvarchar(50) 
)

GO
```

Once you have the table type you can pass table variables of that type to sp_executesql. For example:

```
DECLARE @Categories CategoryTableType
INSERT INTO @Categories 
VALUES (1, 'Beverages'), (2, 'Confections')

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT * FROM @Categories', 
    N'@Categories CategoryTableType READONLY', 
    @Categories
```

sp_executesql cannot access variables of any kind declared outside the sql statement passed to sp_executesql.

However sp_executesql can access to temporary tables created in the calling scope stack. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE  #Categories ( 
    CategoryID int, 
    CategoryName nvarchar(50) 
)
INSERT INTO #Categories VALUES
(1, 'Beverages'), (2, 'Confections')


EXEC dbo.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM #Categories'

DROP TABLE #Categories
```

On the other hand the calling scope cannot access to temporary tables created in the sql statement passed to sp_executesql. For example the following code will fail with Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Invalid object name '#Categories'.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql N'
    CREATE TABLE  #Categories ( 
        CategoryID int, 
        CategoryName nvarchar(50) 
    )
    INSERT INTO #Categories VALUES
    (1, ''Beverages''), (2, ''Confections'')'

SELECT * FROM #Categories
```

Also, the calling scope cannot access to any variable declared inside the sql statement passed to sp_executesql